# Deﬁne $f : Z/3Z → Z/3Z$ by $f ([a]) = [2a + 1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, equivalence-relations, formal-proofs

Just finished proving this is well-defined, how do I prove it's surjective and injective?

I know that injective means that if $x1 \neq  x2$, then $f(x_1) \neq f(x2)$, i.e. each value in the domain is uniquely mapped to an element in the codomain, with no duplicates.

Not sure how to even begin to prove this though.

Comment: Perhaps I can start with a contrapositive.

Assume f([a1]) = f([a2]). Not sure what to do after?

Comment: then 3[a1] + 1 = 3[a2] +1

Comment: so then 3[a1] = 3[a2] and finally [a1] = [a2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[2a+1]=[2b+1]$

$\implies 2a+1-(2b+1)\equiv 0 $mod  3

$\implies 2(a-b) \equiv 0$ mod 3

$\implies 3$ divides $2(a-b)$ and since 3 is prime 3 divides $a-b$

$\implies [a]=[b]$

Since the set is finite injective implies surjective

Comment: we haven't learned anything about if a finite set is injective it's surjective, so I think we need to prove that on it's own.

Comment: Hey please note to say mapping is surjective u need to show for each element in codomain we have an element in domain which is true since mapping is one-one

Comment: did u get it @Test say if u have a problem

Comment: I got as far as: "Let n be an element of Z/3Z. I claim [a] maps to [3a +1]." Not sure what to do after, I'm assuming something to do with  (mod3)